# SAT MATH 2 Geometry problem

Tags: geometry

If a cylinder whose height is equal to the diameter of its base is inscribed in a sphere, then the ratio of the volume of the cylinder to the volume of the sphere is:

A. $\frac12$

b. $\frac{\sqrt2}3$

B. $\frac{2\sqrt2}3$

D. $\sqrt2$

e. $\frac{3\sqrt2}8$

I tried setting the radius of the cylinder of the base to be $r$. And I got the radius of the sphere to be $\sqrt2 \times r$ because the diagonal of the cylinder seems to be the diameter of the sphere. Not sure if I am doing this right. I don't seem to get the answer when I tried it that way!

Excuse my sqrts (fixed), I am not sure how to write it in mathematical form. If possible, a diagram would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start is correct.  The volume of the cylinder is $\pi(r^2)(2r) = 2\pi r^3$ and the volume of the sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi(r\sqrt{2})^3 = \frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}\pi r^3$, so the ratio is $$\frac{2\pi r^3}{\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}\pi r^3} = \frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{8},\ \boxed{E}.$$